# Find the joint mass function

Tags: probability

We roll a fair die 6 times. Let $X=$ the number of 1's observed and $Y=$ the number of 6's observed. Find the joint mass function $p(x,y)$.

Comment: How about trying it yourself first and letting us know where you are having difficulty?

Comment: I know that $X$ and $Y$ are binomial but they are not independent so P(x,y) does not factor. I'm also not clear if these are multinomial. Beyond that I'm unclear on an approach.

Comment: It is not that hard to find things like $P\{X = 1, Y = 0\}$ now, is it? The $1$ can occur in 6 different positions and the remaining $5$ positions are filled with elements from $\{2,3,4,5\}$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this is a multinomial distribution:  there are three possible outcomes of interest.  Either you roll a one with probability $1/6$, a six with probability $1/6$, or a number between two and five with probability $4/6$.  The joint distribution of these outcomes is clearly multinomial with parameters $n = 6$, $p_1 = p_2 = \frac{1}{6}$, and $p_3 = \frac{2}{3}$.  The joint PMF is then $$\Pr[X = x \cap Y = y] = \frac{6!}{x! \, y! \, (6-x-y)!} \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^x \left( \frac{1}{6} \right)^y \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{6-x-y}.$$

Answer (score 0):

First, we choose $x$ dice to be $1$. This can be done in $\binom 6x$ ways. Then, w choose $y$ dice to be $6$: $\binom {n-x}y$ possibilities. There are $n-x-y$ dice left with $4$ possible values, so the total number of possibilities with $x$ ones and $y$ sixes is $\binom nx\binom{n-x}y4^{n-x-y}$. The total number of possibilities is $6^6$, so we get
$$
p(x,y)=\frac{\binom nx\binom{n-x}y4^{n-x-y}}{6^6}
$$
Note that this will be zero when $x<0$, $y<0$ or $y>n-x$ ($x+y>n$). Also, $x$ and $y$ should be integers.